# find string in field of object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, axios

I have string:

```
city = 'Hải Phòng'
```

and an array that I get from an API which looks like this:

```
data = [{},{},{},{ MaTinhThanh: 'xx', TenTinhThanh: 'Hải Phòng' },{},{}]
```

I want to find an object in my data:

```
mycity = data.find( c=>c.TenTinhThanh.includes(city))
```

the above gives `undefined`, but I expect

```
{ MaTinhThanh: 'xx', TenTinhThanh: 'Hải Phòng' }
```

My API endpoint is:

```
https://donhang.vnpost.vn/api/api/TinhThanh/GetAll
```

I am using visual code, Axios, nodejs

I also tried the getting the length of both strings:

```
data[3].TenTinhThanh.length` ====>11
city.length` ====>9
```

What is the problem?

Comment: do you want to search the array for the city given?

Comment: object in array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two strings don't contain the same characters, even though the appear to be visually the same:

```js
const city = "Hải Phòng";
const objV = "Hải Phòng";
console.log(city === objV); // false
```

This is because you're using the [precomposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character) forms of:

- `ả` (*latin small letter a with hook above*)
- `ò` (*latin small letter o with grave*)

in your search string `city`. These precomposed characters are legacy unicode characters, instead, you should be using the decomposed forms, which are the characters being used in your object value:

- `ả` (*latin small letter a* `a`, followed by *combining hook above*  `̉`)
- `ò` (*latin small letter o* `o`, followed by *combining grave accent*  `̀`)

(yes, these are different to the ones listed previously). You can do this by updating your `city` to hold `"Hải Phòng"` (which uses the decomposed characters for `ả` and `ò`). If you can't decompose your string for whatever reason, you can use [`String.prototype.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) on your input string or your object string, eg:

```js
const city = 'Hải Phòng'.normalize("NFD"); // or just use `const city = "Hải Phòng";`

const data = [{},{},{},{ MaTinhThanh: 'xx', TenTinhThanh: 'Hải Phòng' },{},{}];

const mycity = data.find( c=>c.TenTinhThanh?.includes(city));
console.log(mycity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the property exists in the first place, then match against that city value. It looks like there may have been something wrong with the encoding of the strings, because I received an error before I copied the city var value to the object.

Edit: It looks like another user laid out this issue in detail.

```js
let city = 'Hải Phòng';

const data = [{},{},{},{ MaTinhThanh: 'xx', TenTinhThanh: 'Hải Phòng' },{},{}];

let mycity = data.find(c => c.TenTinhThanh && c.TenTinhThanh === city);

console.log(mycity);
```